# react native click highlighted word

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm using [react-native-highlight-words](https://github.com/clauderic/react-native-highlight-words) to highlight hashtagged words in my react-native app. It highlights required words properly but I want to make it clickable too which is not provided by this library. Means when I will click `#positivewibes` word, it redirect me to another page.
I've uploaded the image for reference [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlBMj.png).

**My Code**

```
import Highlighter from 'react-native-highlight-words';

export default class LikeComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            highlightWordArray: []
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        postText = this.props.postData.details;
        var regexp = new RegExp('#([^\\s]*)','g');
        postText = postText.match(regexp);
        if(postText != null) {
            this.setState({highlightWordArray: postText});
        }
    }
    render() {
       return (
         <Highlighter
           highlightStyle={{color: 'red'}}
           searchWords={this.state.highlightWordArray}
           textToHighlight= {this.props.postData.details}
         />
      )}
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank  you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fork and modify the library code by providing an additional prop - `onPress` in the [file](https://github.com/clauderic/react-native-highlight-words/blob/master/index.js) as

```
<Text 
   onPress={props.onPress}
   key={index}
   style={chunk.highlight && highlightStyle}
>
  {text}
</Text>
```

and later use it as

```
<Highlighter
   ...// other props
   onPress={// your redirect instance}
/>
```