# react-native highlight word and make it clickable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

I'm developing a react-native app in which I've to highlight `#tagged word` in paragraph and make that word clickable. I used `react-native-highlight-words` library and it works fine except click event. I also changed it core library for click event but it hangs my system and not work perfectly as solution is given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54414770/react-native-click-highlighted-word) link. I also got an array of `#tagged` words are coming in paragraph but how to give style to that particular word that's I don't know.

**My Code**

```
    import Highlighter from 'react-native-highlight-words';

    export default class LikeComponent extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = {highlightWordArray: []};
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            postText = this.props.postData.details;
            var regexp = new RegExp('#([^\\s]*)','g');
            postText = postText.match(regexp);
            if(postText != null) {
              this.setState({highlightWordArray: postText});
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
          <Highlighter
            highlightStyle={{color: 'red'}}
            searchWords={this.state.highlightWordArray}
            textToHighlight={this.props.postData.details}
            onPress={(value) => console.warn(value)}
         />
   )}
}
```

Is there any solution to highlight `#taggeed` word in `this.props.postData.details` and make it clickable?

Thank you.

Comment: Okay, for just click event you changed core library?

Comment: yes, but is there any another option?

Answer (score 1):

Actually currently `react-native-highlight-words` is just a react-native wrapper of `highlight-words-core`. It gives a component to use in react-native. I checked its library and there is no `onPress` event is attached to `Text` components in react-native-highlight-words.

If you want to perform `onPress` then you have to write onpress functions in core library that is `react-native-highlight-words`.

Create two new `onPress` function in `Highlighter.js` as,

```
Highlighter.propTypes = {
    ...
    ...
    onPressNormalText: PropTypes.func,
    onPressHighlightedText: PropTypes.func
};
```

Then add this onPress functions in Highlighter as,

```
export default function Highlighter({..., ..., onPressNormalText, onPressHighlightedText}) {
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```

Finally add this functions on `Text` components of `Highlighter.js`,

```
return (
    <Text style={style} {...props} onPress={onPressNormalText}>
        {chunks.map((chunk, index) => {
            const text = textToHighlight.substr(chunk.start, chunk.end - chunk.start);

            return !chunk.highlight ? (
                text
            ) : (
                <Text onPress={onPressHighlightedText} key={index} style={chunk.highlight && highlightStyle}>
                    {text}
                </Text>
            );
        })}
    </Text>
);
```

So finally your `Highlighter.js` with `onPress` events looks like,

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { findAll } from "highlight-words-core";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

Highlighter.propTypes = {
    autoEscape: PropTypes.bool,
    highlightStyle: Text.propTypes.style,
    searchWords: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
    textToHighlight: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    sanitize: PropTypes.func,
    style: Text.propTypes.style,
    onPressNormalText: PropTypes.func,
    onPressHighlightedText: PropTypes.func
};

/**
 * Highlights all occurrences of search terms (searchText) within a string (textToHighlight).
 * This function returns an array of strings and <Text> elements (wrapping highlighted words).
 */
export default function Highlighter({
    autoEscape,
    highlightStyle,
    searchWords,
    textToHighlight,
    sanitize,
    onPressNormalText,
    onPressHighlightedText,
    style,
    ...props
}) {
    const chunks = findAll({ textToHighlight, searchWords, sanitize, autoEscape });

    return (
        <Text style={style} {...props} onPress={onPressNormalText}>
            {chunks.map((chunk, index) => {
                const text = textToHighlight.substr(chunk.start, chunk.end - chunk.start);

                return !chunk.highlight ? (
                    text
                ) : (
                    <Text onPress={onPressHighlightedText} key={index} style={chunk.highlight && highlightStyle}>
                        {text}
                    </Text>
                );
            })}
        </Text>
    );
}
```

Now you can use `Highlighter.js` as,

```
<Highlighter
     highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: "yellow" }}
     searchWords={["and", "or", "the"]}
     textToHighlight="The dog is chasing the cat. Or perhaps they re just playing?"
     onPressNormalText={() => console.log("normal text is clickeddd!")}
     onPressHighlightedText={() => console.log("highlighted text is clickked!")     
/>
```

And all done :)

Or if you dont want to do all this, just use my forked version of this library, https://github.com/adityasonel/rn-highlight-words

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the answer by Aditya, we can send the highlighted text like below and do the necessary functions.

```
return (
    <Text style={style} {...props} onPress={onPressNormalText}>
        {chunks.map((chunk, index) => {
            const text = textToHighlight.substr(chunk.start, chunk.end - 
 chunk.start);
            return !chunk.highlight ? (
                text
            ) : (
                <Text onPress={()=>{onPressHighlightedText(text)} key={index} style={chunk.highlight && highlightStyle}>
                    {text}
                </Text>
            );
        })}
    </Text>
)
```